# Winform - multi line Textbox changes scroll position on refresh

Tags: winforms, textbox

I have a winform application that has a textbox, multiline, readonly where I display a kind of log that is refreshed each second. The text box can have more than 100 lines of text.

On each refresh, if the user scroll and selection are lost.
I need a way to allow to the user to keep the scroll and selected text.

I tried to replace only the line that changes - didn't work (using Lines property)

I tried to save the selection before update and re-select it after - didn't work.

I tried to use RichTextBox instead - didn't work.

Anyone did something like this before? Is any library (custom control) I can use instead?

Thank you.

Comment: You using C# or VB.Net?

Comment: Show some code that doesn't work, as well as how you refresh the TextBox...as my initial testing worked fine.

Comment: Consider using a [ListBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox?view=netcore-3.1) all the examples and posts found on here and other forums indicates implementing `System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")` the ListBox is quite flexable and keeps focus and position when selected.